# How to paste a custom linux stdout into a JSON with Python?

Tags: python, json, linux, unix

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to write a script that will take in a unix stdout file and convert it into a JSON format file. The format of the file is the following on every line:

```
inodeNumber fileSize ownerName pathToFile
```

The path can contain whitespaces and backslash characters, an example is:

```
236342512 200 George usr/temp/a\ path/random1.txt
```

Now my problem is that if I use the split(" ") method and store it into a dictionary, the whitespaces in the file path will create more than 1 key-value for the path. I have thought of encoding it but it still won't solve the space problem in the path as that space will be encoded too.

The JSON format I am trying to get is as follows:

```
{
   "files": [{
       "inodeNumber": "236342512",
       "fileSize": "200",
       "ownerName": "George",
       "pathToFile": "usr/temp/a\ path/random1.txt"
    },
    {...}]
}
```

Also, is the best solution to proceed for such a conversion from that custom unix stdout file into JSON to store each attribute into a key-value pair in a Python dictionary and then creating a JSON object and dumping it into a file? I will be working with very large files (over 1gb each!) so performance will need to be taken into consideration too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you know that the first three values don't have spaces, and the remaining value (the path) does, why not take the first three values of the split and assign them as values, and then take the remaining results of the split, and join them back together on a space? It'll be tough for anyone to recommend anything about performance without more background on your use case.

Comment: What do you want the output json to look like? `str.split(" ", 4)`, will fix your splitting issue.

Comment: @imm Thanks for the reply, I have edited my post to include the desired JSON output. So once I get the first 3 values into the array, how would I proceed to join back the path along with the other values? Also which information should I further provide as background? Sorry this is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow so I'm not quite up to par yet :P If this helps I am trying to process over 10 million lines so I'd like to be able to not take too long.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the reply. I have edited my post to include the desired JSON output. Do you think that pushing that array into a dictionary and then dumping it into a JSON would be the fastest way of processing the file?

Comment: If you are going to process that large number of lines, you might not want to store it in JSON - pretty much any non-streaming JSON parser would choke on it.

Comment: @zwer Thanks for the answer. I see, but I need the end result to be a JSON file since that's the only file format I can use afterwards. What do you think of processing the stdout file and storing it into a MongoDB collection then creating a JSON file out of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this method to parse the line, as it does not assumes anything about the path:

```
s = r'236342512 200 George usr/temp/a\ path/random1.txt'

def parseLine(s):
    sList = s.split(' ')
    D = {}
    D['inodeNumber'] = sList[0]
    D['fileSize'] = sList[1]
    D['ownerName'] = sList[2]
    D['pathToFile'] = ' '.join(sList[3:])
    return D

print(parseLine(s))
```

for your example, it gives this output:

```
{'inodeNumber': '236342512', 'fileSize': '200', 'ownerName': 'George', 'pathToFile': 'usr/temp/a\\ path/random1.txt'}
```